# How to make a program wait then skip waiting by a button?

Tags: java, android

I want to make an android application that with show the first element of an array in a textview on the screen then it will wait for 5 seconds then showing the next element in the array. There will be a button under the textview, I want that if I clicked the button the waiting is skipped and the next element is shown.

How to implement this technique in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below thread to run a task in a specific time . Maybe below will serve your issue. Change all variable reference according your code. For next time query try to add your code so that community people can understand what you have done so far. 
Use below code on `onCreate()` method :

```
   int currentPosition = 0 ;
        final String [] array = new String[10];
        for(int i =0 ; i<array.length ; i++){
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final int  position = i ;
            currentPosition = position ;
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(array[position]);
                }
            }, 5000);
        }


        final int position = currentPosition ; 
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView.setText(array[position]);
            }
        });
```